# Is there a way to find the absolute extrema of a function with infinite critical points?

Tags: calculus

Consider a damped sinusoid. It has a obvious absolute maxima, but it also has an infinite number of critical points. Is there a general solution to finding an absolute extrema given a function that has an infinite number of critical points?

Comment: I doubt that there is some realistic general rule that you could apply. When this case occurs, usually there is some pattern to the critical points that you can exploit, such as all lying on some recognizable curve - as in your damped sinusoid example. In that case, you can find the extrema of that curve, then eliminate all critical points of the original function that are far away from those extrema.